What is the origin of the non-analytic behavior of the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{t^3}{t^4+1} J_2(x t) dt$?
I came across integrals of the type $I(x) = \int_0^\infty \frac{t^3}{t^4+1} J_2(x t) dt$
From numerical integration, it seems that when $|x| \rightarrow 0$, the integral is reaching a limiting value close to 0.5 (I am unsure if it is exactly 0.5).
However, $J_2(0)=0$.
How to analytically find the behavior of this integral for small $x$, and what is the reason behind this discontinuity at $x=0$?
Here is a plot of $I(x)$ evaluated numerically.

Turns out that the result is approximately equal to the function $0.5 \exp(-x^2/6)$.
The blue curve is the numerical integral, and the red curve is the fit of $0.5 \exp(-x^2/6)$. Why is the result approximately a Gaussian?


There is some similarity of integrals of the type $\int_0^\infty \frac{sin(tx)}{t} dt$, which is a step function, and has a discontinuity at $x=0$.

Just a guess: Isnt it because this is in the Riemannian sense, not Lesbegue, so we should intepret the upper  limit of the integral really as a limit. And then the limit taking x to 0 and the upper limit to infinity does not commute?

In Mathematica 14.0 use: AsymptoticIntegrate[  t^3/(t^4 + 1)*BesselJ[2, x*t], {t, 0, Infinity}, {x, 0, 4},   Assumptions -> x > 0] gives: $$\frac{1}{384} x^4 \left(-4 \log (x)-2 \gamma +1+\log (256)+\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)+\psi ^{(0)}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)-\frac{\pi  x^2}{32}+\frac{1}{2}$$

Solution for integral is Meijer-G function and using Mathematica: Asymptotic[  1/4  MeijerG[{{}, {}}, {{0, 1/2, 1}, {-(1/2)}}, x^4/256], {x, 0, 4},   Assumptions -> x > 0] we have the same answer.

@MariuszIwaniuk I don't know much about MeijerG function. Please feel free to submit it as an answer.

Well is not a answer only solution from Mathematica.

Under the substitution $u=xt$, the integral becomes $I(x)=\int_0^\infty \frac{u^3}{x^4+u^4}J_2(u),du$. At this point $x\to 0$ yields $\int_0^\infty \frac{J_2(u)}{u}du=\frac12$, which is in line with OP's suspicion. That suggests something delicate going on regarding order of limits.

A further point: If we set an upper cutoff at $t=T$, then the same previous substitution yields $\int_0^{xT} \frac{u^3}{x^4+u^4}J_2(u)~du$. So now if we take $x\to 0$ while holding $s=xT$ fixed, we seemingly obtain $\int_0^s \frac{J_2(u)}{u}du=\frac12-\frac1s J_1(s)$. So the value we get when $(x,T)\to (0,\infty)$ seemingly depends on the path we take to get there.

Contour integration shows that the value of the integral is the real part of  $- K_{2}(|x|e^{i \pi/4})$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.   See this related answer.

Since no answers have been posted, I'm going to turn my comment into an answer.
I will show that $I(x)$ has the series expansion $$I(x) =\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\pi x^{2}}{32} + \frac{x^{4}}{384} \left(\frac{17}{3} -4 \gamma - 4 \ln \left( \frac{x}{2}\right) \right)+ \ldots $$ for $x>0$.
This is what Mathematica returns according to Mariusz Iwaniuk except that Mathematica express the coefficient of the $x^{4}$ term in terms of $\psi \left(\frac{5}{2} \right)$ and $\psi \left(-\frac{1}{2} \right)$.
The above series is  the generalized Puiseux series for $\operatorname{ker}_{2}(x)$.

As Semiclassical showed in a comment above, the integral is indeed approaching $\frac{1}{2}$ as $x \to 0^{+}$ since $I(x)=\int_0^\infty \frac{u^3}{x^4+u^4} \, J_2(u)\, \mathrm du$, which, by the dominated convergence theorem, tends to $\int_0^\infty \frac{J_2(u)}{u}\, \mathrm du = \frac{1}{2}$ as $x \rightarrow 0^{+}$.

In a previous answer I used contour integration to show that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t}{1+t^{4}} \, J_{0}(xt) \, \mathrm dt = - \Im \, K_{0}(xe^{i \pi/4}) = - \operatorname{kei}(x), \quad x >0, $$ and
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{3}}{1+t^{4}} \, J_{0}(xt) \, \mathrm dt =  \Re \, K_{0}(xe^{i \pi/4}) =  \operatorname{ker}(x), \quad x >0. $$
The same approach shows that $$I(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{3}}{1+t^{4}} \, J_{2}(xt) \, \mathrm dt = - \Re \, K_{2}(xe^{i \pi/4})= \operatorname{ker}_{2}(x) , \quad x >0. $$
The principal branch of $K_{2}(z)$ has the series expansion $$ K_{2}(z)=  \frac{2}{z^{2}} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{z}{2} \right)^{2} \sum_{k=0 }^{\infty} \left(\psi(k+1) +\psi(k+3)-2 \ln \left(\frac{z}{2} \right) \right) \frac{\left(\frac{z}{2} \right)^{2k}}{k!(k+2)!}.  $$
This series can be obtained from the definition $$ \begin{align} K_{2}(z) &= \frac{\pi}{2} \lim_{\nu \to 2} \frac{I_{-\nu}(z) - I_{\nu}(z)}{\cos(\pi v)} \\ &= \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \nu } I_{-\nu}(z)\bigg|_{\nu =2} - \frac{\partial }{\partial \nu}I_{\nu}(z) \bigg|_{\nu  = 2} \right) \\ &=  -\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \nu } I_{\nu}(z)\bigg|_{\nu =-2} + \frac{\partial }{\partial \nu}I_{\nu}(z) \bigg|_{\nu  = 2} \right) \end{align}$$
by replacing $I_{\nu}(z)$ with it's series expansion and differentiating termwise.
(See  section $3 \cdot 52$ in the textbook A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions by Watson for the derivation of the very similar series for $Y_{n}(z)$.)
Replacing $z$ with $xe^{i \pi/4}$, $x >0$, we have $$K_{2}(xe^{i \pi/4}) = - \frac{2i}{x^{2}} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{i}{2} \left(\frac{x}{2} \right)^{2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\psi(k+1)+ \psi(k+3) -2 \ln \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) - \frac{i \pi}{2} \right) \frac{(i)^{k} \left(\frac{x}{2} \right)^{2k}}{k!(k+2)!} $$
Multiplying both sides of the above equation by $-1$ and equating the real parts of both sides, we have
$$\begin{align} -\Re \, K_{2}(xe^{i \pi/4})  &=I(x) \\ &= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4} \left(\frac{x}{2} \right)^{2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{4k}}{(2k)!(2k+2)!} \\ &+ \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\psi(2k+2)+ \psi(2k+4)- 2 \ln \left(\frac{x}{2} \right) \right) \frac{(-1)^{k} \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{4k+2}}{(2k+1)!(2k+3)!} \\&= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\pi x^{2}}{32} + \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{x}{2} \right)^{2} \left(\psi(2)+ \psi(4) - 2 \ln \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \right) \frac{\left(\frac{x}{2} \right)^{2}}{1!3!} + \ldots \\&= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\pi x^{2}}{32}+ \frac{x^{4}}{384} \left(\frac{17}{3}-4 \gamma-4 \ln \left(\frac{x}{2} \right) \right) + \ldots.\end{align} $$
The next term in the series is $\frac{\pi x^{6}}{12,288}$.
